# The construction "pronoun"+"to be" +"adjective" + ... issue

Tags: grammar

If the construction works for all the sentences below ?

1. He is important to do it. == It is important for him to do it.
2. He is happy to do it. == It is happy for him to do it.
3. I am sorry to do it. == It is sorry for me to do it.

Comment: I'd answer but I don't know **why**... so I'll tell you that for #1, **only** the second option is correct while, for #2 and #3 **only** the first option is correct.

Comment: @Marek Jasper's answer is good. To simplify it, you can think about it like this: in *He is happy to do it*, doing it makes him happy; but in *It is important for him to do it*, doing it doesn't make him important. (It's because it's important, he should or must do it.)

Answer (score 2):

"**It is important for him to do it.**" means "It is important [to somebody or something] that he is the one to do it."  Perhaps "It is much more likely to work if he does it." or "He won't learn how to do it, unless he does it himself."

"He is important to do it." does not seem correct to my (American) ear.

"**He is happy to do it.**" means "He does it happily." or "He is happy to have the chance to do it."

"It is happy for him to do it." does not seem correct -- who is happy?  "It was a happy chance that he did it." is grammatically correct, but old-fashioned.

"**I am sorry to do it.**" means "Doing it makes me sad." or "I am sad that I must do such a thing."

"It is sorry for me to do it." either is not correct (who is sorry?) or uses a different meaning of "sorry".  (In the previous sentence, "sorry" means "sad" or "apologetic".  In this sentence, "sorry" could mean "pitiable" or "pathetic".)

Comment: So, I understand that the construction "It is 'adjective' for him/her to 'verb' .." works but only for some adjectives like: important, urgent, suggested, recommended . Instead, for "sorry,happy..." that it doesn't work. Is it true?